# how to increase RAM of AVD (android virtual device)?

Tags: android, performance, windows-7, ram, android-virtual-device

Hi I am working on win7 64 bit system , AVD running quite slow  on it maybe due to only 70 MB RAM available to it. As shown in settings > applications > running services 
there it says `54 mb ram used 16 mb ram available .`

is there any way to increase this RAM ??

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the 'device memory' size of an AVD during creation, just add it as 'new hardware', but the AVD emulator is slow, get used to it :-)